# How to add listview webpart to subsite, while list is available in top level site?

Tags: list, xslt-list-view-web-part, sub-site

I have a list on the top level site collection. I would like to show the list items in a webpart on the welcome page of a subsite. I have implemented this already in a CQWP(content query webpart). But I would like to use the listview webpart. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

Here are the steps:

1. Export your xslt list view web part.
2. Open exported `.webpart` file and find `<property name="WebId"`. There will  be empty guid.
3. Put into the `WebId` property the ID of your root web.
4. Go to sub site.
5. Edit page.
6. Click Insert -> web part.
7. Choose "Upload web part".
8. Select your updated `.webpart` file.
9. Click Upload.
10. After upload click again Insert -> Web part. This time select "Imported web parts" group in the left.
11. Select your xslt web part and to the sub site.
12. Finish! :)

**NOTE**
By default it is not possible to export xslt web part, but you can enable this option by using following powershell:

```
$WebUrl = "http://intranet.contoso.com"
$PageUrl = "/Pages/default.aspx"
$WebPartName = "Documents"

# Enables export mode
$Web = Get-SPWeb $WebUrl
$File = $Web.GetFile($Web.ServerRelativeUrl + $PageUrl)
$File.CheckOut()
$Wpm = $File.GetLimitedWebPartManager([System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PersonalizationScope]::Shared)
$WebParts = $Wpm.WebParts
$WebPart = $WebParts | where { $_.Title -eq $WebPartName }
$WebPart.ExportMode = [System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebPartExportMode]::All
$Wpm.SaveChanges($WebPart)
$File.CheckIn("", [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPCheckInType]::MajorCheckIn)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible via list view webpart, CQWP is the alternative in OOTB way. You can also use custom js code to display data. :)